# How to use sexagesimal syntax in arguments of FFmpeg or if impossible how to convert it in Windows CMD shell

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

*Question updated 2020-12-06 to enlarge the scope without discarding the prior answer which applies to both prior and larger cases.*

I had trouble to provide a sexagesimal time (`HH:MM:SS.mm`) to a filter option that was not an expression. For instance `trim` filter.
*It happens there is an escaping rule i did not know yet when i first asked, and was addressed in the first comment by @Gyan.*

The problem is universal, but the solution may depend on the shell *if we go the scripting route*... and i am currently stuck with **Windows's CMD.exe**.

For instance the following skips one minute and 4 tenths of seconds in all streams as accurately as it can seek each, then invokes the trim filter to keep the segment between one and two minutes of the remaining duration, and do so with two different syntaxes. This example happens to be compatible with both CMD and BASH shells so no escaping hell.

```
ffmpeg -ss "1:00.4" -i INPUT -vf "trim=start='1\:00':end='120'" OUTPUT
```

Then how do we achieve the same in the **expressions** within the filters ?
If we cannot avoid using the scripting of the shell, i am looking for a Windows CMD solution.
*I had posted one answer with a piece of script to convert a textual sexagesimal time to a textual decimal fractional time in seconds, which was not useful for the original case, but may apply to more generic cases and in particular to the expressions.*

Example of **failed** attempt with one expression in the `select` filter.

```
ffmpeg -ss "1:00.4" -i INPUT -vf "select='between(t,1\:00',120)'" OUTPUT
```

The sexagesimal notation seems to not be supported by ffmpeg filter expressions as i found no reference of it in the documentation nor in SO/web.

I browsed through the list of functions defined in ffmpeg expression library but did not find any way to parse the sexagesimal input there yet, nor any way to use text in its semantics.

However i found some unrelated example that hard-coded some arithmetical expression to provide the numerical decimal amount of seconds equivalent to what was intended, such as `2*60+2` to mean `2:02`.

The polynome used above to compute seconds may use preprocessing of shell variable, whichever shell it is, but we need to parse the components of `HH:MM:SS.mm` to put them in those variable first. You know, using bash `$var` or cmd `%var%`/`%~1` styles. Otherwise we may compute the polynome completely in the shell instead of the expression but it is so much trouble for little gain.

So while CMD still exists ~~like an undead and becomes really dead~~, and while i do not have the opportunity yet to replace it, i wish for an answer that either :

- does not need the shell/script at all, OR
- provide a solution in Windows CMD, although relying on it as little as possible.

Reminder and clarification, the use case assumes that we are given a textual sexagesimal time as input and intend to use it in an expression of ffmpeg filter with as little shell dependency as possible or otherwise satisfy Windows CMD.

Comment: Just see https://superuser.com/q/1145777/

Comment: Thank you. Your @Gyan comment definetely links to the exact solution. And now i feel silly for giving so much effort at constructing the post for naught in the wrong direction, just because i misunderstood the escapes of quote and colon before.

Comment: The escaping of colon by antislash `\:` you linked me to was proper solution for most parameters of filters, but it failed with **expressions** which trigger parsing errors, so i updated the question to make it more clear and potentially more useful than my prior misunderstanding where i believed that the trim filter in particular was not working with sexagesimal. Both original and updated question may be leveraged to some extent by the answer i had already submitted to convert time textually.

Answer (score 1):

This is a batch script (for CMD.exe) i wrote to convert the string input time from sexagesimal to decimal despite the very limited and outdated shell. I figured it might be useful to a windows user who like me does not have the skill or permission to use a different shell.

```
    REM May be inserted in another script to call :second or called as a file batch such as "hms-to-second.cmd".
    :second
    REM Convert sexagesimal time plus decimal period into decimal signed number as a string with possible period by parsing that string.
    REM param 1 is name of result destination
    REM param 2 is name of source env-var
    REM param 3 is prefix character of source
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        set "inp=!%~2!"
        set "t=0"
        set "neg="
        if "!inp:~0,0!"=="-" (
            set "inp=!inp:~1!"
            set "neg=-"
        )
        for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%G in ( "!inp!" ) do (
            call :stepparse t "%%G"
            call :stepparse t "%%H"
            call :stepparse t "%%I"
        )
        (
            endlocal
            set "%~1=%neg%%t%"
        )
    exit/b
    
    :stepparse
    REM Call this repetitively from high weight to low weight, assuming the higher weight never are empty. Assume there is at most one dot for a decimal part which is appended (with the dot) because CMD SET/A cannot compute decimals.
    REM param 1 is name of accumulator
    REM param 2 is input
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        set "x=!%~1!"
        for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=." %%E in ( "%~2" ) do (
            if not [%%E]==[] set /a "x=x*60+%%E"
            if not [%%F]==[] set "x=!x!.%%F"
        )
        (
            endlocal
            set "%~1=%x%"
        )
    exit/b
```

Use it like this.

```
set "begin=1:2"
set "end=2:3"
call hms-to-second.cmd begin %begin%
call hms-to-second.cmd end %end%
ffmpeg -i sample-counter.mp4 -vf "trim=start='%begin%':end='%end%'" sample-counter-trimmed.mp4
```